# How to manage multiple HTML elements with same name using WTForms, Jinja & Python

Tags: python, jinja2, wtforms

I had defined an HTML template with Jinja, where I had defined three (3) textfields with same name. Then in the backend using the get_all method I collected all the values.

Then in order to add form validation, etc, I added WTForms library. Then I defined a Form as:

```
class RoleForm(BaseForm):
    name = fields.TextField(_('Name'))
```

And in the HTML page I rendered this element three (3) times.

Now, when I submit the form and the validation fails, I re-render the template using the form as input. But instead each element has the value I had entered, all textfields have the value of the 1st textfield.

Moreover if validation is ok, I use form.name.data, which does not give me all the data from the three textfields, but only the first one.

Do you know how I can handle such situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`wtforms.fields.FieldList`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) field enclosure:

```
class RoleForm(BaseForm):
    name = fields.FieldList(fields.TextField(_('Name')), min_entries=3)
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't going to generate input fields with the same name. It will generate 3 entries with the names: name-0, name-1, name2.

Comment: @Tarantula - as I read the OP the desired behavior is to preserve the state of each text box, not to have three text boxes with the same name :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create HTML `input`elements like this for instance:

```
<input name="row-{{ loop.index0 }}" type="checkbox">
```

It will render inputs like the ones below:

```
<input name="row-0" type="checkbox">
<input name="row-1" type="checkbox">
```

Inside a loop or something like that. Then you'll be able to retrieve the Form contents:

```
class ListForm(Form):
    row = FieldList(fields.TextField('Row'))
```